# phpMyAdmin is showing "The mysqli extension is missing. "?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to install phpmyadmin for a while, and i always face the same error

[image: screenshot]

I downloaded php7.0 and mysql-server-5.7

I also choose Apache2 and unix socket in the configuration process

Also tried adding `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` to the end of the file solution

and when I try to open the `http://localhost/phpadmin` it shows this error

> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
>   See our documentation for more information.

Any help?

[PHP MY Admin Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9WJG.png)

Comment: How did you download and install `php7.0`?  From source code, or from a PPA?  Or from the repositories?  What Ubuntu version are you on?

Comment: I downloaded it using repository. I am on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the software `php-mysql`.  This will install `php7.0`'s MySQL interface libraries to the proper locations.

You can install it with: `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

After installation, restart your Apache2 instance - `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

PHP should then detect the mysql and mysqli libraries.

Comment: it worked and now I can open the local host but there is another problem appeared, I updated the question with a screen shot

Comment: @HwangHeeRa_Gogo That's a different issue, so you need to open a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that I have to specify the version number of the extension to make it work:

```
apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

Because I had upgraded PHP from 5.6 to 7.2